# Excel recognizing the EVALUATE function in one workbook but not in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula, evaluate

I am trying to create a formula in Excel that converts distances in feet and inches, written in the ft-in format (for example, 20-6) into inches only (246 in this example). I am looking at an Excel workbook created by someone else where this is done by means of the following formula:

`=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!C2,"-","*12+"))`, i.e., the hyphen is replaced with "*12+" and the whole string is then evaluated. Cell C2 is the location of the ft-in number.

However, when I try to write a similar formula in another Excel file, I get a #NAME? error. After examining my formula, I don't see what could be causing the error except the EVALUATE function. Why is it that the same version of Excel, running on the same computer, recognizes EVALUATE in one Excel file but, apparently, not in another?

Comment: EVALUATE is not a native function.  Either in your name manager you have a function named that or you have a vba function named that in the workbook in which it works.  You will need to copy that to the new workbook for it to work

Comment: I think the real question is, what's the use of it as without `EVALUATE()` it would work for both versions

Comment: @P.b `=LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1&"-")-1)*12 + IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),0)`

Comment: Ah, so `EVALUATE` had an actual function there